# How to compile a C# class library for 32-bit in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2019, 32bit-64bit, class-library

In a C# class library project, the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox is grayed-out in Visual Studio 2019.  Would setting the configuration to `x86` in the Configuration Manager be sufficient to ensure that the class library is compiled to target 32-bit?

The background to my question is that Windows 10 Update 1903 causes a WinForms project targeting .NET Framework 4.8 to crash with an InvalidProgramException when the project is opened in the debugger and it happens to employ components from an (award-winning and widely used) third-party component suite. The company writes that the only way they have discovered to avoid the problem is to "ensure the application is compiled to target 32bit".  I don't have Windows 10 update 1903 on my PC yet, so I can't test, but I would like to know how to "ensure" that everything is 32-bit before that upgrade is forced upon my machine.

[image: Solution Configuration]

Comment: You just need to compile your executable project as x86. All other projects can be Any CPU.

Comment: You are on the right avenue - the x86 target platform is exactly what you need. You may find the [Back to Basics: 32-bit and 64-bit confusion around x86 and x64 and the .NET Framework and CLR](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasics32bitAnd64bitConfusionAroundX86AndX64AndTheNETFrameworkAndCLR.aspx) article helpful.